# github action retrieve environment variable value from terraform ASG?

Tags: github, terraform, github-actions

In my github action there's a yml file. In the yml file is a section for environment variables.
They're hardcoded and it no longer should be.
I would like to get value from the *.tfvars file or from terraform module main.tf.
Is that possible?
Currently:

```
env: 
  capacity: 2
```

I would like to be

```
env: 
  capacity: ${{from_terrafrom_asg.capacity}}
```

Comment: Tools utilized within GH Actions steps cannot assign environment variables intrinsically within the config. Sometimes they can assign in-process environment variables though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can dynamically set environment variables in your GitHub Actions workflow based on values from a Terraform configuration. To achieve this, you'll need to use a combination of the GitHub Actions outputs and the Terraform output values.
e.g:-
# main.tf

```
output "capacity" {
  value = 2
}
```

Now, you can modify your GitHub Actions workflow YAML file to capture this output and set it as an environment variable:

```
yaml
name: Your Workflow Name

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
      with:
        terraform_version: 0.15.0

    - name: Initialize Terraform
      run: terraform init

    - name: Apply Terraform
      id: terraform
      run: terraform apply -auto-approve
      continue-on-error: true

    - name: Set environment variable from Terraform output
      run: echo "capacity=${{ steps.terraform.outputs.capacity }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: Display environment variables
      run: cat $GITHUB_ENV

    # Continue with the rest of your workflow...
```

GitHub Actions workflow initializes Terraform, applies the configuration, and then uses the echo command to append the Terraform output value to the GitHub Actions environment file ($GITHUB_ENV). Afterward, you can reference this environment variable in subsequent steps in your workflow.

Comment: thank you very much kind stranger on the internet!